# Путешествие в главном меню

Tags: html, javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы при наведении на ссылку, она расходилась в подкатегории, потом в подкатегорию, та еще на подподкатегории. Как меню на сайте zarabotokwm.ucoz.hu без форума. Какой тег этому способствует?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дам, пожалуй, вам ссылку. Значит, пройдете по ней, нажмете - посмотреть исходный код. И все это внесете в  блок меня сайта. Он раньше использовался мной, вам просто придется заменить на свое ссылки и названия. [В блок](http://phptesting.h19.ru/x_php/x/menu.html). А это добавляем в свой CSS файл [CSS](http://phptesting.h19.ru/x_php/x/m.css).

Нет такого тега, это связка html+css+javascript. Впредь задавать такие вопросы следует на специальных форумах, посвященных ucoz!

Comment: Вы что все такие злые? =) Чем юкоз "хуже" друпала или джумлы?

Comment: Мы не злые,просто стыдно такое тут задавать)
Да уж ты явный фан ucoz)Ты сейчас сравниваешь небо с землей,как можно их сравнивать xD